# Why am I getting an output of 0

Tags: c

Why am I getting an output of 0? I think there's something wrong about my angle conversion and possibly my equation, yet fiddling around with it and moving some stuff always gives me the same result.

My goal is to write a C code that will compute the angle θ for any two given vectors u and v.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()

{
    double ux, uy;
    double vx, vy;
    double inner_product(double vx, double vy, double ux, double uy);
    double v;
    double u;
    double i;
    double x;
    double k;
    double pi;
    double angle;
    double p;
    ux = 1.0;
    uy = 1.0;
    vx = 1.0;
    vy = 1.0;



    printf ("input value for ux\n", ux);
    scanf_s ("%f", &ux);

    printf ("input value for uy\n", uy);
    scanf_s ("%f", &uy);

    printf ("input value for vx\n", vx);
    scanf_s ("%f", &vx);

    printf("input value for vy\n", vy);
    scanf_s ("%f", &vy);

    u = ux * vx;
    v = uy * vy;
    i = u * v;
    x = u * u;
    k = v * v;
    pi = acos(-1.0);
    p = acos(i / (sqrt(x * k)));
    angle = ((p * 180) / pi); //converting from radians to degrees


    printf("%f", angle);

return;

}
```

Comment: A good place to start would be to enable compiler warnings, and to eliminate them.  Look at the first several `printf` calls.  You're passing values that are unused.  Why?  Remove them.

Comment: @TomKarzes by removing the ux=... I get the uninitialized error, how would I be able to eliminate these errors?

Comment: @DanielRossi 1. Initialize variables to read for in case the readings fail or check return values of reading function to check if readings are successful. 2. Delete unused *arguments of `printf()`*. Note that excess arguments on `printf()` are just evaluated and ignored, so they are not harmful.

Comment: Sadly the assignment dictates we use acos

Comment: I didn't say anything about the assignments.  I said you were passing unused arguments to `printf`.  Yes, they should be harmless, but it makes no sense.  It's bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math error is in the following:

```
p = acos(i / (sqrt(x * k)));
```

Change it to:

```
p = acos((ux*vx + uy*vy) / (sqrt(ux*ux + uy*uy) * sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)));
```

That's just the dot product divided by the two lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You equation is wrong.
The correct is:

```
|U|=√[Ux^2+Uy^2]
|V|=√[Vx^2+Vy^2]
U*V=(Ux,Uy)(Vx,Vy)=Ux*Uy+Vx*Vy
cos=U*V/[|U|*|V|]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `%f` but `%lf` specifier have to be used to read data having type `double` via `scanf()` family.

Note that `%f` should be used to *print* data having type `double` via `printf()` family because `float` will be automatically converted to `double` for variable number arguments.

Comment: Changing it to %lf still gives me an output of 0

Comment: "Note that `%f` should be used to print data having type `double`" - bad advice. Since C99 `printf` also supports `%lf`, which works with `double`.  Quite the opposite, for consistency, `%f` should be *always* reserved for `float` and `float` only, in both `printf` and `scanf`. Values of type `double` should *always* be used with `%lf`, again, in both `printf` and `scanf`. Support for `%lf` in `printf` was added in C99 *specifically* to support that consistency.

Comment: @DanielRossi What is your input? I got `180.000000` for input `10 20 -30 40`. Check your formula.

Comment: In other words, `%f` *can* be used to `printf` `double` values, but it should *not* be used that way. It should be avoided as a bad practice. `%f` is for `float`, `%lf` is for `double` - everywhere.

Comment: The values I have to input are ux=0.5, uy=1.0, vx=3.0, and vy=4.0. The answer should be 10.3 degrees